# Invalid object name 'EventQueue' when I try to login to sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sqlexception

Can anyone help on this? I can see the sitecore login page but when I try to login, I got error that shows

```
"Invalid object name 'EventQueue'. "
```

Exception Detail is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'EventQueue'`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the query that you used to retrieve the values

Comment: I found this query in the stack trace. DataException: Error executing SQL command:  SELECT MAX([STAMP]) FROM [EventQueue]

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently upgrade the solution?  If so, did you use the DBCT tool?  If so you should create 'Notifications' and 'EventQueue' tables manually because these tables are missed after the database conversion.  You can find the SQL queries to do that on the SDN.

Answer (score 1):

Your database version does not match your Sitecore version.

The EventQueues table was introduced in Sitecore 6.3 and is added by the SQL script found here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sitecore6/updates/sitecorecms630.zip

If your Sitecore version was recently upgraded, it was not done properly and more problems can occur. So i would really think about what went wrong there and maybe start over.

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure the EventQueue table was not created under a different schema.  In the example shown below, the EventQueue table is not under the dbo schema like the rest of the tables.  If a sql user under the dbo schema executes a select query, it will result in Invalid Object name because the table name in the query is not prefixed with the schema.

`SELECT * from EventQueue`  Returns Invalid Object Name

`SELECT * from sitecore.EventQueue` Works

To fix this, either change the EventQueue table to be part of the dbo schema or ensure the sql user has the proper default schema. In our case, this error cropped up when we added the sysadmin role to the sql user. [When sql users are assigned to the sysadmin role, the default schema is ignored and the default schema becomes dbo.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)  So ironically, adding permissions caused the problem.

[image: EventQueue table does not have the dbo schema]